# Installing two different versions of Windows via BootCamp?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, high-sierra, apple-inc

I am using a Mid-2013 MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra. I have installed Windows 10 on it using bootcamp.

Can I also install Windows 7 on it using BootCamp and run it alongside Windows 10 and macOS High Sierra? i.e., while starting up, I can hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> and select between the three installed OS.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and found that you can’t install two different operating systems. When I tried, I came to the installation screen and nothing responds.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't see why not.
It's looking like Boot Camp wants 48GB minimum for a partition, and a system I'm working on right now is allowing me to do 16 partitions 
(251 GB drive, with 106 used. 1 partition with 106 GB, and 15 with 9.6 GB each.)
I'll test it out next week with a system with a larger drive.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct. I have heard there may be a hard limit of four partitions on any HD/SSD to be bootable and I believe macOS with a single drive has three on it's only drive. Though you may be able to do it with an external drive.